# Shell Script output odd

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to Shell Script programming. I am attempting to make a program that outputs only gives back the odd arguments. For example, "I am a robot" should give "I a" only.

I thought I could use the shift command to through the arguments along with while and if statements, but I am unsure of how to convey a division by 2 with a remainder of 1 in the square brackets in the if statement ([])

```
#!/bin/sh
X=$1
shift
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  if [ "HELP HERE" ]; then
     X=$1
     echo $X
  fi
  shift
 done
echo $X
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just shifting twice?

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    X=$1
    echo $X
    shift
    shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a much better idea

Comment: This would be better written as `shift 2`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That does *not* work. `shift 2` won't `shift` anything if `$# < 2`, and therefore if an odd number of arguments is provided it will *loop forever*.

Comment: But by that token, won't you get an error from the second shift?  The `ksh` I use on Linux gives an error message (`ksh: nothing to shift`) when I do `shift` on an empty argument list (or `shift 2` on a one entry argument list). ... Answer: `bash` is more sensible and doesn't generate a message (but doesn't shift anything when you try to shift more items than there are to shift). So, differences between shells — what fun. I didn't expect the error from `ksh`; I expected `shift 2` to shift 1 when there aren't two left. (`/bin/sh` on Solaris gives an error but does do the shift.)  Weird!

Answer (score 0):

nneonneo's idea must be better than the following, but I'm going to present a way that checks if the argument is odd just in case.

```
#!/bin/sh
cnt=1
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  X=$1

  # output the current argument when the counter is odd.
  if [ $(($cnt%2)) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo $X
  fi

  cnt=$(($cnt+1))
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ODD
declare -a EVEN
ODDIX=0
EVENIX=0

while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    if (( $#%2 == 1 ));then
        ODD[$ODDIX]=$1
        ODDIX=$((ODDIX+1))
    else        
        EVEN[$EVENIX]=$1
        EVENIX=$((EVENIX+1))
    fi
    shift
done

echo ODD: ${ODD[@]}
echo EVEN: ${EVEN[@]}*
```